# Bash script to find the frequency of every letter in a file

Tags: linux, bash, frequency, letters

I am trying to find out the frequency of appearance of every letter in the english alphabet in an input file. How can I do this in a bash script?

Comment: Why are you using bash for this?

Comment: Found this programming question somewhere!! I guess perl would be the better alternative, isn't it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just one awk command

```
awk -vFS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)w[$i]++}END{for(i in w) print i,w[i]}' file
```

if you want case insensitive, add `tolower()`

```
awk -vFS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)w[tolower($i)]++}END{for(i in w) print i,w[i]}' file
```

and  if you want only characters,

```
awk -vFS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ if($i~/[a-zA-Z]/) { w[tolower($i)]++} } }END{for(i in w) print i,w[i]}' file
```

and if you want only digits, change `/[a-zA-Z]/` to `/[0-9]/`

if you do not want to show unicode, do  `export LC_ALL=C`

Comment: I am sorry I am not very familiar with awk. The solution works but I am getting all characters instead of just alphanumeric characters.        awk -vFS="" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)w[tolower($i)]++ sum++ } END{for(i in w) print i,w[i],w[i]/sum}'

Comment: Thanks again. I am wondering why I get results like ü 2 and é 2, when the regex is [a-zA-Z].

Comment: that's because gawk's regex works for unicode characters. (UTF8).

Comment: how can i remove them in that case?

Comment: you can do a `export LC_ALL=C`.

Answer (score 36):

My solution using `grep`, `sort` and `uniq`.

```
grep -o . file | sort | uniq -c
```

Ignore case:

```
grep -o . file | sort -f | uniq -ic
```

Comment: how can I get frequency / sum(all frequencies) after this?

Comment: @SkypeMeSM to get frequency of each character, just divide by the total number of characters (which is given by `wc -c file`).

Answer (score 9):

A solution with `sed`, `sort` and `uniq`:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file | sort | uniq -c
```

This counts all characters, not only letters. You can filter out with:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file | grep '[A-Za-z]' | sort | uniq -c
```

If you want to consider uppercase and lowercase as same, just add a translation:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\n/g' file | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | grep '[a-z]' | sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Thanks. This considers uppercase and lowercase characters as separate. How can I calculate the frequencies where we consider A and a as same?

Comment: Yes this works great as well. I am wondering how can I calculate the probabilities i.e. frequency/total sum. We will need to pipe the output again to sed again but I cannot figure out the regex involved?

Comment: You can add some `wc`, `cut`, `dc`, `tee` and other commands but it would be more juggling with plates than a maintainable work. I think that adding more features would be easier with a perl script.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a suggestion:

```
while read -n 1 c
do
    echo "$c"
done < "$INPUT_FILE" | grep '[[:alpha:]]' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to mouviciel's answer above, but more generic for Bourne and Korn shells used on BSD systems, when you don't have GNU sed, which supports \n in a replacement, you can backslash escape a newline:

```
sed -e's/./&\
/g' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

or to avoid the visual split on the screen, insert a literal newline by type CTRL+V CTRL+J

```
sed -e's/./&\^J/g' file | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```