# How can I count the frequency of letters

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a data like this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR
>sp|P13674|P4HA1_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-1 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA1 PE=1 SV=2
VECCPNCRGTGMQIRIHQIGPGMVQQIQSVCMECQGHGERISPKDRCKSCNGRKIVREKKILEVHIDKGMKDGQKITFHGEGDQEPGLEPGDIIIVLDQKDHAVFTRRGEDLFMCMDIQLVEALCGFQKPISTLDNRTIVITSHPGQIVKHGDIKCVLNEGMPIYRRPYEKGRLIIEFKVNFPENGFLSPDKLSLLEKLLPERKEVEE
>sp|Q7Z4N8|P4HA3_HUMAN Prolyl 4-hydroxylase subunit alpha-3 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=P4HA3 PE=1 SV=1
MTEQMTLRGTLKGHNGWVTQIATTPQFPDMILSASRDKTIIMWKLTRDETNYGIPQRALRGHSHFVSDVVISSDGQFALSGSWDGTLRLWDLTTGTTTRRFVGHTKDVLSVAFSSDNRQIVSGSRDKTIKLWNTLGVCKYTVQDESHSEWVSCVRFSPNSSNPIIVSCGWDKLVKVWNLANCKLK
>sp|P04637|P53_HUMAN Cellular tumor antigen p53 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53 PE=1 SV=4
IQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQL
>sp|P10144|GRAB_HUMAN Granzyme B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=GZMB PE=1 SV=2
MQPILLLLAFLLLPRADAGEIIGGHEAKPHSRPYMAYLMIWDQKSLKRCGGFLIRDDFVLTAAHCWGSSINVTLGAHNIKEQEPTQQFIPVKRPIPHPAYNPKNFSNDIMLLQLERKAKRTRAVQPLRLPSNKAQVKPGQTCSVAGWGQTAPLGKHSHTLQEVKMTVQEDRKCES
>sp|Q9UHX1|PUF60_HUMAN Poly(U)-binding-splicing factor PUF60 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=PUF60 PE=1 SV=1
MGKDYYQTLGLARGASDEEIKRAYRRQALRYHPDKNKEPGAEEKFKEIAEAYDVLSDPRKREIFDRYGEEGLKGSGPSGGSGGGANGTSFSYTFHGDPHAMFAEFFGGRNPFDTFFGQRNGEEGMDIDDPFSGFPMGMGGFTNVNFGRSRSAQEPARKKQDPPVTHDLRVSLEEIYSGCTKKMKISHK
>sp|Q06416|P5F1B_HUMAN Putative POU domain, class 5, transcription factor 1B OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=POU5F1B PE=5 SV=2
IVVKGHSTCLSEGALSPDGTVLATASHDGYVKFWQIYIEGQDEPRCLHEWKPHDGRPLSCLLFCDNHKKQDPDVPFWRFLITGADQNRELKMWCTVSWTCLQTIRFSPDIFSSVSVPPSLKVCLDLSAEYLILSDVQRKVLYVMELLQNQEEGHACFSSISEFLLTHPVLSFGIQVVSRCRLRHTEVLPAEEENDSLGADGTHGAGAMESAAGVLIKLFCVHTKALQDVQIRFQPQLNPDVVAPLPTHTAHEDFTFGESRPELGSEGLGSAAHGSQPDLRRIVELPAPADFLSLSSETKPKLMTPDAFMTPSASLQQITASPSSSSSGSSSSSSSSSSSLTAVSAMSSTSAVDPSLTRPPEELTLSPKLQLDGSLTMSSSGSLQASPRGLLPGLLPAPADKLTPKGPGQVPTATSALSLELQEVEP
>sp|O14683|P5I11_HUMAN Tumor protein p53-inducible protein 11 OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=TP53I11 PE=1 SV=2
MIHNYMEHLERTKLHQLSGSDQLESTAHSRIRKERPISLGIFPLPAGDGLLTPDAQKGGETPGSEQWKFQELSQPRSHTSLKVSNSPEPQKAVEQEDELSDVSQGGSKATTPASTANSDVATIPTDTPLKEENEGFVKVTDAPNKSEISKHIEVQVAQETRNVSTGSAENEEKSEVQAIIESTPELDMDKDLSGYKGSSTPTKGIENKAFDRNTESLFEELSSAGSGLIGDVDEGADLLGMGREVENLILENTQLLETKNALNIVKNDLIAKVDELTCEKDVLQGELEAVKQAKLKLEEKNRELEEELRKARAEAEDARQKAKDDDDSDIPTAQRKRFTRVEMARVLMERNQYKERLMELQEAVRWTEMIRASRENPAMQEKKRSSIWQFFSRLFSSSSNTTKKPEPPVNLKYNAPTSHVTPSVK
```

I want to count how many of each letter is there, so if I have one I count like this

```
>sp|Q96A73|P33MX_HUMAN Putative monooxygenase p33MONOX OS=Homo sapiens OX=9606 GN=KIAA1191 PE=1 SV=1
RNDDDDTSVCLGTRQCSWFAGCTNRTWNSSAVPLIGLPNTQDYKWVDRNSGLTWSGNDTCLYSCQNQTKGLLYQLFRNLFCSYGLTEAHGKWRCADASITNDKGHDGHRTPTWWLTGSNLTLSVNNSGLFFLCGNGVYKGFPPKWSGRCGLGYLVPSLTRYLTLNASQITNLRSFIHKVTPHR

cat input.txt | grep -v ">" | fold -w1 | sort | uniq -c



   6 A
   9 C
  10 D
   1 E
   7 F
  18 G
   5 H
   4 I
   7 K
  21 L
  15 N
   7 P
   6 Q
  11 R
  16 S
  18 T
   7 V
   8 W
   7 Y
```

however, I want to calculate for all in a better way and more efficient especially when the data is huge

Comment: are you reporting counts line by line or once for the whole file?

Comment: @karakfa for the entire file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash script to find the frequency of every letter in a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966820/bash-script-to-find-the-frequency-of-every-letter-in-a-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Counting characters in strings can easily be done with awk. To do this, you make use of the function `gsub`:

> **`gsub(ere, repl[, in])`**
>   Behave like `sub` (see below), except that it shall replace all occurrences of the regular expression (like the ed utility global substitute) in `$0` or in the `in` argument when specified.
>
> **`sub(ere, repl[, in  ])`**
>   Substitute the string `repl` in place of the first instance of the extended regular expression `ERE` in string in **and return the number of substitutions**. <snip> If `in` is omitted, awk shall use the current record (`$0`) in its place.
>
> **<sub>source: [Awk Posix Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

The following two functions perform the counting in this way:

```
function countCharacters(str) {
    while(str != "") { c=substr(str,1,1); a[toupper[c]]+=gsub(c,"",str) }
}
```

or if there might appear a lot of equal consecutive characters, the following solution might shave off a couple of seconds.

```
function countCharacters2(str) {
    n=length(str)
    while(str != "") { c=substr(str,1,1); gsub(c"+","",str);
       m=length(str); a[toupper[c]]+=n-m; n=m
    }
}
```

Below you find 4 implementations based on the first function. The first two run on a standard awk, the latter two on an optimized version for fasta-files:

**1. Read sequence and processes it line by line:**

```
awk '!/^>/{s=$0; while(s!="") { c=substr(s,1,1); a[c]+=gsub(c,"",s) } }
     END {for(c in a) print c,a[c]}' file
```

**2. concatenate all sequences and process it in the end:**

```
awk '!/^>/{s=s $0 }
     END {while(s!="") { c=substr(s,1,1); a[c]+=gsub(c,"",s) }
         for(c in a) print c,a[c]}' file
```

**3. Same as 1 but use `bioawk`:**

```
bioawk -c fastx '{while ($seq!=""){ c=substr($seq,1,1);a[c]+=gsub(c,"",$seq) } }
                 END{ for(c in a) print c,a[c] }' file
```

**4. Same as 2 but use `bioawk`:**

```
bioawk -c fastx '{s=s $seq}
                 END { while(s!="") { c=substr(s,1,1); a[c]+=gsub(c,"",s) }
                       for(c in a) print c,a[c]}' file
```

Here are some timing results based on [this fasta-file](http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/chromosomes/chrY.fa.gz)

```
OP            : grep,sort,uniq : 47.548 s
EdMorton 1    : awk            : 39.992 s
EdMorton 2    : awk,sort,uniq  : 53.965 s
kvantour 1    : awk            : 18.661 s
kvantour 2    : awk            :  9.309 s
kvantour 3    : bioawk         :  1.838 s
kvantour 4    : bioawk         :  1.838 s
karafka       : awk            : 38.139 s
stack0114106 1: perl           : 22.754 s
stack0114106 2: perl           : 13.648 s
stack0114106 3: perl (zdim)    :  7.759 s
```

---

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, this is not really optimal This is more an O(n^2) solution than O(n) (due to `gsub`)

Comment: `gsub` counting is smart idea.

Comment: Wow, this `bioawk` is really efficient. Thanks for all of these :)

Comment: It just ocurred to me that for `1` saving $0 in a string and then match()/gsub()-ing on THAT might be more efficient than operating directly on $0 since every time you change $0 you might invoke field splitting again (depending on your awk implementation - some only do field splitting if a field is explicitly mentioned in the script).

Comment: @EdMorton I just ran the test. I did not see a difference in time, but you are correct. With some awk implementation, this will be different. (updated the implementation)

Comment: I wish everyone on StackExchange explained their answers this well!

Answer (score 4):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
!/^>/ {
    for (i=1; i<=length($0); i++) {
        cnt[substr($0,i,1)]++
    }
}
END {
    for (char in cnt) {
        print char, cnt[char]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A 107
N 67
P 107
C 41
Q 88
D 102
E 132
R 101
F 65
S 168
G 140
T 115
H 52
I 84
V 101
W 27
K 114
Y 30
L 174
M 39
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v ORS= '!/^>/{gsub(/./,"&\n"); print}' file | sort | uniq -c
    107 A
     41 C
    102 D
    132 E
     65 F
    140 G
     52 H
     84 I
    114 K
    174 L
     39 M
     67 N
    107 P
     88 Q
    101 R
    168 S
    115 T
    101 V
     27 W
     30 Y
```

Comment: @Ed Morton `awk: syntax error at source line 1 source file tst.awk
 context is
 cat >>>  tst. <<< awk
awk: bailing out at source line 11`

Comment: @Learner Look again at my answer, you're not doing what it shows. Seems like you might have copied the `cat` line into the awk script.

Comment: I was thinking about this solution when I saw this question, but I thought multiple `substr` will be a lot more inefficient than that split once only. However I'm not sure about this, am I thinking right this time?

Comment: @Tiw splitting on a null char isn't portable - it'll split into chars in some awks, leave the whole line as-is in others, and can do anything else and still be POSIX compliant since that';s undefined behavior. I really don't know if a single split() would be more efficient than a multiple substr()s or not but IMHO the portability is more important in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Try this Perl solution for better performance.

```
$ perl -lne ' 
            if( ! /^>/ ) { while(/./g) { $kv{$&}++} }  
        END { for ( sort keys %kv) { print "$_ $kv{$_}" }} 
' learner.txt
A 107
C 41
D 102
E 132
F 65
G 140
H 52
I 84
K 114
L 174
M 39
N 67
P 107
Q 88
R 101
S 168
T 115
V 101
W 27
Y 30

$
```

One more solution using Perl, optimized for performance.

```
$ time perl -lne ' 
     if( ! /^>/ ) { for($i=0;$i<length($_);$i++) 
     { $x=substr($_,$i,1); $kv{$x}++ } }  
    END { for ( sort keys %kv) { print "$_ $kv{$_}" }} 
' chrY.fa
A 2994088
C 1876822
G 1889305
N 30812232
T 3002884
a 4892104
c 3408967
g 3397589
n 140
t 4953284

real    0m15.922s
user    0m15.750s
sys     0m0.108s

$
```

---

**Edit with further performance optimizations**

All timings reported below are averages over 3-5 runs on a desktop, done at around the same time but swapped around to avoid pronounced cacheing effects.

Changing the C-style `for` loop to `for my $i (0..length($_))` speeds the second solution from 9.2 seconds to 6.8 seconds.

Then, also removing a scalar (`$x`) at each operation, with

```
if (not /^>/) { for $i (0..length($_)) { ++$kv{ substr($_,$i,1) } } }
```

speeds this up to **5.3 seconds**.

Further reducing variable use, by copying `$_` and thus freeing up the loop to use `$_`

```
if (not /^>/) { $l=$_; ++$kv{ substr($l,$_,1) } for 0..length($l) }
```

only helps a little, running at **5.2 seconds**.

This compares with the `awk` solution, given as `kvantour 2` in nice comparisons in [kvantour answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713467/4653379), at **6.5 seconds** (on this system).

Of course none of this can be compared to the optimized `bioawk` (C-code?) program. For that we'd need to write this in C (which is not very hard using `Inline C`).

Note that removing a sub call (to `substr`) for every character by using

```
if (not /^>/) { ++$kv{$_} for split //; }
```

results in "only" a **6.4 seconds** average, not as good as the above tweaks; this was a surprise.

These times are on a desktop with v5.16.  On v5.24, on the same machine, the best-case (`substr` with no extra variables in the loop) time is 4.8 seconds while the one without the `substr` (but with `split`) is 5.8 seconds.  It's nice to see that newer versions of Perl perform better, at least in these cases.

For reference and easy timing by others, complete code for the best run

```
time perl -lne'
    if (not /^>/) { $l=$_; ++$kv{ substr($l,$_,1) } for 0..length($l) }
    END { for ( sort keys %kv) { print "$_ $kv{$_}" }}
' chrY.fa
```

Comment: added your solution to the timing table: 22.745 seconds

Comment: Thanks @kvantour.. I added one more solution by optimizing it.. in my machine it took 15.92 secs for your big file.. ````bioawk```` is great!

Comment: added your second solution (13sec)

Comment: @kvantour  Note further improvements.

Comment: @stack0114106  I took the liberty of adding a section to your answer. If that's not to your liking I apologize, please let me know and I'll split it into a separate answer. I thought that it best fits here since it simply tweaks your code.

Comment: @zdim I'll add the timing to the list tomorrow. You might have added it as a separate solution though. Nice explanation

Comment: @zdim.. great research and optimizations..learning a lot.. you are welcome to add this.. thank you!

Comment: @kvantour  "_might have added it as a separate solution_" -- it does mostly tweak the code in this answer so I felt it best fit here.  (A reminder to add it to your list, if you wish.)

Comment: @zdim added your solution

Answer (score 1):

not sure how much faster this would be but if you try please post your timings

```
$ awk '!/^>/ {n=split($0,a,""); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[a[i]]++} 
       END   {for(k in c) print k,c[k]}' file | sort

A 6
C 9
D 10
E 1
F 7
G 18
H 5
I 4
K 7
L 21
N 15
P 7
Q 6
R 11
S 16
T 18
V 7
W 8
Y 7
```

this reports counts for the file, not line by line.  As noted below, not all `awk`'s support empty string split.

Here are the timings of the three approaches:

```
$ time grep -v ">" filey | fold -w1 | sort | uniq -c >/dev/null

real    0m11.470s
user    0m11.746s
sys     0m0.260s

$ time awk '{n=split($0,a,""); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[a[i]++]} END{for(k in c) print k,c[k]}' filey >/dev/null 

real    0m7.441s
user    0m7.334s
sys     0m0.060s

$ time awk '{n=length($0); for(i=1;i<=n;i++) c[substr($0,i,1)]++} END{for(k in c) print k,c[k]}' filey >/dev/null

real    0m5.055s
user    0m4.979s
sys     0m0.047s
```

for the test file

```
$ wc filey

  118098   649539 16828965 filey
```

it surprised me that `substr` is faster than `split`.  Perhaps due to array allocation.

Comment: You should mention that splitting on a null char is undefined behavior per POSIX so it'll only work in some awks, e.g. GNU awk.

Comment: @Tiw You misunderstood my comment. In `split($0,a,"")` the problem isn't with `$0` being a null string, it's with `""` being a null string. Using a null string as the "regexp" to split on is undefined behavior per POSIX. That's true whether it's the value of FS or the 3rd arg to split().

Comment: Oh, you mean that... I'm sorry I did misunderstood.  Tried it on Freebsd's `awk` and it worked well though.  @EdMorton

Comment: @Tiw Yes some awks will do what you want but others won't. See [the POSIX awk spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) - when discussing FS `If FS is a null string, the behavior is unspecified.` and later in the `split(...,fs)` synopsis `The effect of a null string as the value of fs is unspecified.`.

Comment: Also added some timings to my answer.