# Find files having more than one occurrence of a pattern on the same line

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file in fasta format as in example below. I would like to extract entries from that file  when sequence: 'CGTACG' occurs more than once.

```
>seq1
AAATTCCGTACGGGCCTCT
>seq2
TGGAATCACAGCGGCGTACGCAGCGGCGGCTGCGGCCGTACGGCG
>seq3
AATGCCAAACGTACGAACAT
```

In the example the output would be (as the sequence 'CGTACG' occurs twice):

```
>seq2
TGGAATCACAGCGGCGTACGCAGCGGCGGCTGCGGCCGTACGGCG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
for file in *; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue # skip if not a regular file
    if ! awk -v seq=CGTACG '$0 ~ seq".*"seq {exit(1)}' "$file"; then
        # the file has two or more occurrences of the string on the same line, process it
        # more code
    fi
done
```

`awk` looks for the string in each file and exits 1 as soon as it finds a line that has two or more occurrences of the string.  `if !` test makes sure that we pick up the file only when `awk` has an exit code of 1.

If we looking for more than one match on *different* lines, then:

```
for file in *; do
    [[ -f "$file" ]] || continue # skip if not a regular file
    if ! awk -v seq=CGTACG '$0 ~ seq {x++; if(x>1) exit(1)}' "$file"; then
        # the file has two or more occurrences of the string on different lines, process it
        # more code
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 4):

All you need is:

```
awk '/^>/{seq=$0} gsub(/CGTACG/,"&") > 1{print seq ORS $0}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another using given string as field separator:

```
$ awk -F"CGTACG" '/^>/{p=$0;next} NF>2{print p ORS $0}' file
```

Output:

```
>seq2
TGGAATCACAGCGGCGTACGCAGCGGCGGCTGCGGCCGTACGGCG
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -F"CGTACG" '    # using the substring as field separator
/^>/ {                # buffer the seqn record for possible use if match
    b=$0
    next
} 
NF>2 {                # if field count more than 2 ie. at least 2 field separators
    print b ORS $0    # output
}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension to the question: [how can I count the frequency of letters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54712459)

```
awk -v subseq="CGTACG" '
     />/ && gsub(subseq,subseq,seq) > 1 { print name; print seq }
     />/{name=$0;seq="";next}
     {seq=seq $0}
     END { if(gsub(subseq,subseq,seq) > 1) { print name; print seq } }
    ' file.fasta
```

This method merges all multi-line sequences in a single line and checks if `subseq` appears more than ones. It does this using the `gsub` function:

> **`gsub(ere, repl[, in])`**
>   Behave like `sub` (see below), except that it shall replace all occurrences of the regular expression (like the ed utility global substitute) in `$0` or in the `in` argument when specified.
>
> **`sub(ere, repl[, in  ])`**
>   Substitute the string `repl` in place of the first instance of the extended regular expression `ERE` in string in **and return the number of substitutions**. <snip> If `in` is omitted, awk shall use the current record (`$0`) in its place.
>
> **<sub>source: [Awk Posix Standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)</sub>**

This, however, can be cleaned up a bit:

```
awk -v subseq="CGTACG" '
     function count_subseq(seq,subseq,   t) {
         t=seq;gsub(RS,RS,t)
         return gsub(subseq,subseq,t)
     }
     />/ && count_subseq(seq,subseq) > 1 { print name; print seq }
     />/{name=$0;seq="";next}
     {seq=seq RS $0}
     END { if(count_subseq(seq,subseq) > 1) { print name; print seq } }
    ' file.fasta
```

Identically, using `bioawk`, you can do

```
bioawk -c fastx -v subseq="CGTACG" '(gsub(subseq,subseq,seq)>1){print ">"$name; print $seq}' file.fasta
```

---

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~bwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_13_13).